# Is there a way to pass through "find" before map_reduce for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

The following line works:

```
Analytic.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce).find
```

but is there a way to do

```
Analytic.collection.find('page_type' => 'products').map_reduce(map, reduce).find
```

and even filter a date range such as `date >= "2010-08-01" and date <= "2010-08-31"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the query option (see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Overview).  Any normal query will work, so yes, you can do a date range.